# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, Is passing an array as a prop to a functional component not possible?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, undefined, react-props

I am following a MERN stack tutorial in which a parent component Dashboard passes an array of objects from its own props (after mapStateToProps) to another component Education. Trying to iterate through this array in Education component gives me the above mentioned error. Please help, the tutorial seemed to have no errors and I have followed it perfectly so why the issue?

`<Education education={profile.education}/>`

(passing the prop in Dashboard.js) education is an array of objects inside an object profile which is a prop mapped from the state. The profile prop is used in other lines in the same component and does not give any other errors.

```
const Education = ({education}) => {
    const educations = education.map(edu => (
    <tr key={edu._id}>
        <td>{edu.institute}</td>
        <td>{edu.course}</td>
        <td>
        <Moment format='YYYY/MM/DD'>{edu.from}</Moment - <Moment 
         format='YYYY/MM/DD'>{edu.to}</Moment>
        </td>
        <td className="btn brick">
            Delete
        </td>
    </tr>
    ));

     ...return block with JSX that renders when {educations} is omitted
}
```

(trying to iterate in Education.js)

EDIT: Full Dashboard.js code

```
import React ,{Fragment,useEffect} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {getCurrentProfile} from '../../actions/profile';
import Spinner from '../layouts/Spinner';
import DashboardActions from './DashboardActions';
import Education from './Education';

const Dashboard = ({getCurrentProfile, auth, profile}) => {

useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();
}, []);


return (
    profile.loading && profile.profile === null ? <Spinner /> : <Fragment>
        <h1 className="large text-primary">Dashboard</h1>
        <p className="lead">Welcome {auth.user && auth.user.name }</p>
        {profile.profile !== null
        ?
        <Fragment>
            <DashboardActions/>
            <Education education={profile.education}/>
        </Fragment>
        : 
        <Fragment>
            <p>You have not yet set up a profile, please add some 
information about yourself</p>
            <Link to="/create_profile" className="btn btn-primary">Create 
Profile</Link>
        </Fragment>}
    </Fragment>
    );
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
auth: state.auth,
profile: state.profile
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getCurrentProfile})(Dashboard);
```

Comment: At some point the `education` prop is likely `undefined`. Can you link to the tutorial and include more code? How is this component being called and used?

Comment: You need to add the rest of the code too. This is not enough to know where the true problem lies. What does the initial state object look like?

Comment: The tutorial is a paid course by Brad Traversy on Udemy. MERN stack social media project course.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `console.log(education)` to see the value of education?

I think it is `undefined` while the profile is loading.

you could try `const educations = education && education.map(edu => (`

Comment: I also want to suggest that instead of saying the `profile` prop is simply *some* object, actually define its shape, i.e. which properties it has, and which are actually required in order to function properly. I agree that `education` is likely undefined, but why is the profile defined but somehow missing the education property?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I was stuck on for a long time.

The cause of mine was very obscure, but I was importing an object `History` where I would pass the PropType object to.

I then created a PropType `history` in my `Progress` object, to which I defined in the propTypes object.

```
import History from "../components/class/History";
...
const Progress = ({ history, ...
...
    <History data_in={history}/>
...
Progress.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
...
```

The collision of `History` imported and history created as a PropType was causing the object to be passed into `History` as undefined, therefore the `.map` was being called on an undefined object.

I'm not sure if anyone will manage to reproduce it but It could help someone. :)